# how to get result from a website to which we wish to send data?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to write an program that sends data to website and result is evaluated by the website and result is send back to the program.

Which language would be the best supported for this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried reading about WebScraping. I don't know whether it relates to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, You can use web services for your requirement. Use [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ASP.Net Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) in .Net platform.

Comment: But what if the OP is using a LAMP configuration? This question should be closed for being primarily opinion-based